# C++ Memory Not Being Reclaimed for Objects That Leave Scope - at my wits end

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm having problems with a particular memory leak that I'm unable to identify. Gigs of memory.

In this particular case, all of the objects are on the stack (though most do create something on the heap). The objects are very short lived and, for the most part, live in for loops. I don't know exactly what's going on, but their accumulated corpses stay in memory. I've done enough debugging to determine that their creation (and subsequent failure of deletion from memory) are the cause for the memory waste.

Through quite a bit of testing, I've verified that the number of times the constructors are called is equal to the number of times the destructor is called. One of the classes is a virtual class, so I made sure that its destructor was virtual (it was). Valgrind doesn't point to any memory leaks. I'm not sure what else to try. I'm almost thinking I'm hitting a compiler bug, but usually that means that I'm wrong.

If someone can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Below are the basic classes I'm using. I've recreated the concept of a generator in C++ using them. They're pretty much the crux of my entire program:

```
/**
 * @file    generator.hpp
 * @brief   Macros and class to create generators
 *
 * @author  Adam Baxter
 * @version 2.0
 * @date    2012/07/11
 * @copyright 2012
 */

#ifndef apollo_generator_hpp_
#define apollo_generator_hpp_

/**
 * @brief A macro to define the beginning of a generator's operator() function
 */
#define $gen_start if(_line < 0) { _line = 0;} \
switch(_line) { case 0:;

/**
 * @brief A macro to define the end of a generator's operator() function
 */
#define $gen_stop  } _line = 0; return false;

/**
 * @brief A macro to yield the generator's current position and create that corrosponding return value
 */
#define $yield(R)    \
do { \
    _line = __LINE__; \
    generate(R); return true; case __LINE__:; \
} while (0);

namespace apollo {

/**
 * @class   Generator generator.hpp "generator.hpp"
 * @brief   Standard generator interface for all generators in this project.

     The macros above, coupled with this class, are used to define functions that can be jumped into and out at arbitrary positions

    Consider NumGen, a simple number generator:

    class NumGen : public Generator<int> {

    NumGen() : _i(0), Generator<int>() {}

    bool operator()(value_type &rv) {
        $gen_start;
        for(_i = 0; _i < 10; _i++) {
            $yield(rv);
        }
        $gen_stop;
    }

    void generate(value_type &rv) {
        rv = _i;
    }

    private:
        value_type _i;
    };

    NumGen is nothing more than a simple for-loop that yields numbers [0,10).
    The importance of the generator is to separate out the generator's next state calculation (_i++)
    from the return value's generator (rv = _i) from the rest of the application logic

    The more complex of a state we're working with, the more powerful this idea becomes. 

    @Note Successive calls to operator() will place execution directly after
        the last called yield statement
        - Any variable modification between $gen_start and $yield will be skipped! -
        A generator's state must be held in its member variables and care must be exercised when using 
        local variables in operator().
 */

template <typename T>
class Generator {
public:

    /**
     * The type the generator creates
     */
    typedef T value_type;

    // default ctor
    Generator(): _line(-1) {}

    // copy ctor
    Generator(Generator const &rhs) : _line(rhs._line) {}

    // move ctor
    Generator(Generator &&rhs) : _line(rhs._line) {}

    // copy = ctor
    Generator& operator=(Generator const &rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            _line = rhs._line;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // move = ctor
    Generator& operator=(Generator &&rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            _line = rhs._line;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    /**
    * Generator calculates its next state, creates the value for that state.
    *
    * @param[in,out] rv The return value's storage location
    *
    * @return True if generator at next state and a new return value is generated. 
    *   False if there are no more valid states and return value is untouched.
    */
    virtual bool operator()(value_type &rv) = 0;

    /**
     * Using the generator's current state, create the return value
     *
     *  @param[in,out]  rv The return value's storage location
     */
    virtual void generate(value_type &rv) const = 0; 

    // == operator
    virtual bool operator==(Generator const &rhs) const {
        return _line == rhs._line;
    }

    // deconstructor
    virtual ~Generator() {}

protected:
    int _line; /**< The source code line $gen_start will use for its switch */
};

} /* namespace apollo */

#endif // apollo_generator_hpp_
```

and

```
/**
 * @file    generatoriterator.hpp
 * @brief   A class to create iterators out of generators
 *
 * @author  Adam Baxter
 * @version 2.0
 * @date    2012/07/11
 * @copyright 2012
 */

#ifndef apollo_generatoriterator_hpp_
#define apollo_generatoriterator_hpp_

#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

namespace apollo {

template <typename G>
class GeneratorIterator : public boost::iterator_facade <
    GeneratorIterator<G>,
    const typename G::value_type,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag> {
public:
    typedef G generator_t;

    GeneratorIterator() : _finished(true) {}

    explicit GeneratorIterator(generator_t const &gen) :
        _gen(gen),
        _finished(false) {
            this->operator++();
    }

    explicit GeneratorIterator(generator_t &&gen) :
        _gen(std::forward<generator_t>(gen)),
        _finished(false) {
            this->operator++();
    }

    GeneratorIterator(GeneratorIterator const &rhs) :
        _gen(rhs._gen),
        _finished(rhs._finished) {
            if (!_finished) {
                _gen.generate(_rv);
            }
        }

    GeneratorIterator(GeneratorIterator &&rhs) :
        _gen(std::move(rhs._gen)),
        _rv(std::move(rhs._rv)),
        _finished(rhs._finished) {}

    GeneratorIterator& operator=(GeneratorIterator const &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            _gen = rhs._gen;
            _finished = rhs._finished;
            if (!_finished) {
                _gen.generate(_rv);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    GeneratorIterator& operator=(GeneratorIterator &&rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            _gen = std::move(rhs._gen);
            _rv = std::move(rhs._rv);
            _finished = rhs._finished;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    generator_t const& gen() const {
        return _gen;
    }

    ~GeneratorIterator() {}

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    generator_t _gen;
    typename generator_t::value_type _rv;
    bool _finished;

    bool equal(GeneratorIterator const &rhs) const {
        if (_finished || rhs._finished) {
            if (_finished && rhs._finished) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }  else if ((_rv == rhs._rv) &&
            (_gen == rhs._gen)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void increment() { advance(); }

    void advance(std::ptrdiff_t dist = 1) {
        while (!_finished && (dist > 0)) {
            if( _gen(_rv) == false) {
                _finished = true;
            }
            dist -= 1;
        }
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t distance_to(GeneratorIterator const &rhs) const {
        using std::distance;
        if (_finished && rhs._finished) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (!_finished) {
            return distance(*this, rhs);
        } else {
            return distance(rhs, *this) * -1;
        }
    }

    const typename generator_t::value_type& dereference() const { return _rv; }

};

template<class G, typename... Args>
GeneratorIterator<G> make_geniter(Args && ...args) {
    return GeneratorIterator<G>(G(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

} /* namespace apollo */

#endif /* apollo_generatoriterator_hpp_ */
```

Comment: anyway you con create a simple example of this problem?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. It appears to be Boost code, not mine.

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out what was going on. The memory problem is due to a bug I'm still tracking down in Boost::flat_map and friends where flat_map.insert(iterator,iterator) causes memory leaks. However, I didn't recognize it because I'd called flatmap(const &flatmap). I guess down the line it still does the same thing.